# Eigenstates Involving Function Multiplication

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, notation, linear-algebra

I am a novice to linear algebra fundamentals and quantum physics. From lecture today, my lecturer went over the importance of writing an operator in terms of the basis it reflecting in which it is quite trivial to setup
$$\hat{O}f = o f$$
for a eigenstate.

We also have that we can define functions in a one-dimensional sense using projection
$$\langle x | g \rangle = g(x)$$
such that typically one would perform this projection when designing the approach to their solution for their operator.

My difficulty lies in connecting these two concepts for operators like
$$\hat{O}=g(\hat{x}) \times $$
such that imposing my first equation leads to a conundrum. Using my undergraduate study readings, I found a statement stating that operators of this form tend to share the same eigenvectors of $|x \rangle$ or simply the basis of x. How does this make sense using the definition of eigenvalues/eigenvectors?

Comment: In your very first line how can $f$ be an arbitrary function yet satisfy the eigenvalue equation for $\hat{O}$?

Comment: Sorry, mate. I am new to this forgot the part where it is an eigenstate.

Answer (score 1):

We have $\hat x |x_0\rangle = x_0 |x_0\rangle$. Now take for example $g(x)=x^2$, i.e., $\hat O = \hat x^2$. Then,
$$ \hat O |x_0\rangle = \hat x^2 |x_0\rangle = \hat x ( x_0 |x_0\rangle ) = x_0^2 |x_0\rangle . $$
You can easily check that you get an analogous result for any polynomial $g$.

For non polynomial functions, we would have to go into the details of how $\hat O$ gets defined in the first place, but I think the calculation above is enough to motivate why this should be true.